# Handwritten text to digital versions - software, libraries, options

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, text, image, text-extraction

What types of (presumably machine learning) software/libraries exist for taking handwritten text in tables into a digital format? The tables may not always be the same. So I assume it might be fairly complex.

Alternatively has anyone used e.g. the amazon textract service and know of the cost per image to do this?